# how to remove loads of white space / new lines from in text body of email from rails 3 mail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, whitespace

I have an email that i display the text_body to my users within my rails 3 application.

Problem is the text_body comes in with loads of white space between lines / paragraphs and when i display it with simple_format to show formatted text it has loads of 
 in.

Does anyone know how to remove this to make the email look like it should ie formatted properly on the page in browser ?

thanks a lot
Rick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite fast

```
text.squeeze(" \t")
```

It leaves at most one adjacent space and/or tab anywhere in the text.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply strip some unwanted spaces with something like:

`text.strip.gsub(/\s*\n\s*/, "\n")`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using ERB to create the email, be aware that <% %> will add a new line in the output. If you want to avoid that new line, use <% -%> instead. (Not saying this is your issue, but you might want to look into it.)